# Bootstrap glyphicon in button not behaving like supposed in mobile and internet explorer

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

In my template I have a navigation button staying on the left side of the page as the user scroll down, triggering a menu when clicked.

In this button, I put a bootstrap glyphicon :

```
<div class="nav" id="sidebar">
    <button class="toggle-slide-left btn btn-custom btn-cutsom-cat">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
    </button>
</div>
```

The glyphicon is well centered horizontally when the page is on desktop (high resolution), and when reduced on *Firefox*. But on mobile or with Internet Explorer, when the page get smaller (so the button too), the glyphicon stays on the right of the button, like if there was some sort of padding-left.

I tried to put `pading-left: 0px; padding-right: 0px;` in the button's CSS, but it makes the glyphicon overflow when reducing the resolution.

Here is my CSS :

```
.btn-custom-cat{
    height: 30px;
    width: 80%;
    margin-left: 5%;
    text-align: center;
}
#sidebar.affix-top {
  position: fixed;
  margin-top: 10px;
  width: 5%;
} 
#sidebar.affix {
  position: fixed;
  top: 60px;
  width: 5%;
}
```

Firefox 30 full screen :

[image: Firefox30 full screen]

Firefox 30 reduced width :

[image: Firefox30 reduced width]

IE10 full screen :

[image: IE10 full screen]

IE10 reduced width (problem here) :

[image: IE10 reduced width (Problem here!)]

You can see the website at this address (reduce the menu to see the button I'm talking about) : (removed after answer was given)

Comment: can you provide your code in jsfiddle ?

Comment: Can you provide jsfiddle of codepen demo?

Comment: What's your IE version? Mobile: what's your browser? Can you share a bootply.com link?

Comment: Edited with screenshots + address of website

Comment: I'm in no way affiliated with them, but [FontAwesome](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/) will likely save you loads of trouble and are a vast improvement over the glyphicons. Better yet, no JavaScript required and they work in the same way as glyphicons HTML-wise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<button class="toggle-slide-left btn btn-custom btn-custom-cat" style="padding: 0; min-width: 20px;">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
</button>
```

This works for me perfectly. If you want to maintain original `top` and `bottom` padding, simply use `padding-left: 0; padding-right: 0` instead of `padding: 0`.

Comment: We're getting closer here. Just need to add a min-width to the button on top of this and it'll prevent the button to be smaller than the glyphicon (it was automatic before). Just add min-width: 20px to the button style on your answer and I'll accept it. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure if it will work (don't have IE available atm), but could you try removing whitespace inside the button? So you would get

```
<div class="nav" id="sidebar">
    <button class="toggle-slide-left btn btn-custom btn-cutsom-cat"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span></button>
</div>
```

Comment: In fact this is already like this in my template. I changed it when posting here so it'd be easier to read. Thanks for the answer though, but didn't solve my problem :)

Comment: In the code your posted, it is not like this. You have put the span on a seperate line, introducing newspace between the button and the span tags. Are you sure you tried what I suggested?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is visible using the "box model" view in the inspect element tab in chrome or firefox.

Your glyphicon span has a width greater than the internal width of the button.  This is because the button is set to 80% width and so it gets very small internally due to the padding (24px in total).  When this happens the glyphicon "starts" at the "start" of the inside of the button, but because the button is too small it overflows into the padding of the button thus making it look wrong.

An easy fix for this is one line of css on the button

```
min-width: 38px;
```

This will ensure that there will always be space for the glyphicon inside the button.

**EDIT**

To ensure that the button won't overflow into the text, ensure the text won't get big enough to.  Change the `.container-margin` css style to this.

```
.container-margin {
    max-width: calc(100% - 50px);
    margin-right:5%;
}
```

Then the text will never get too wide for the button

Comment: In Firefox, the button can be reduced to smaller than 38px width, still the glyphicon stay centered. I'd like to reproduce this in any browsers. The problem with a fixed min-width is that it overflows on other containers (the word "Salut" for example), and I want to avoid that (and keep the 80% ratio).

Comment: That is firefox's (gecko) interpretation of the overflowing of spans into buttons.

Chrome has the "too small a button" issue as well

Comment: I keep the question open for now to see if there is a way to force the browser to center it while overflowing. Maybe I should customize the glyphicon to remove the "white spaces" on the right and left side?

Comment: I just edited my answer to deal with the overflowing into other containers

Comment: Not working for all width (with minimum width it's not overflowing, but on dynamic resize (between min width and max width) it overflows). I'll try to make a jsfiddle so it's easier for you to try.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `clearfix` class in the span.